# How to make the request stronger using “Please”

Tags: grammaticality, adverbs, word-order, adverb-position

I understand, we can use the word “please” before, middle and after the sentence.

Would like to know just by changing position of word “please” in any sentence,

```
How to make a strong request?
Position of “please” to make request very polite?
Position of “please “ to emphasis on something?
```

Could anyone please help?
Thanks.

Comment: Adding *please* would always make the request more polite. To make the urgency of the request clear it would be best at the end along with an exclamation point [!]. The emphasis being on the *please* would both strengthen the effort to be polite and the grave nature of the request. It would almost serve as a second sentence reiterating the first.

Comment: "Pretty please with sugar on it."

Comment: At the end of your question, you ask, "Could anyone please help?" What would you do with "please" in that sentence to make the request stronger or weaker or to emphasize any of the other words?

Answer (score -1):

Using please to create a stronger request is possible in spoken English but putting additional stress on the word please when speaking the sentence and changing the tone of speech. Obviously, this is more challenging to accomplish using only written English, and I don't think you can achieve that by changing only the position of the word within the sentence. Similarly, I don't think the politeness is altered by the location within the sentence.

On a side note, in spoken English, the methods of altering the politeness and strength of the request are essentially opposites of each other, so you would not be able to make it stronger **and** more polite at the same time (i.e. making the request stronger would make it inherently less polite because you are changing it from a request to a command).